# PHP loses Square Brackets From Sent jQuery form data

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to save form information using jQuery by serializing as an array and adding it into an object. jQuery sends the information fine as such:

```
action:save
form_data[name]:
form_data[date-requested]:09/23/2014
form_data[purchase-order-requested]:yes
form_data[vendor]:sdf
form_data[item-description[]]:
form_data[item-number[]]:
form_data[cost[]]:
form_data[quantity[]]:
```

But, when I try to print_r the posted data it appears as this:

```
Array
(
    [name] => 
    [date-requested] => 09/23/2014
    [purchase-order-requested] => yes
    [vendor] => sdf
    [item-description[] => 
    [item-number[] => 
    [cost[] => 
    [quantity[] => 
)
```

What can I do with inputs that have brackets in them?

[EDIT]
Here would be the jQuery:

```
var form_data = form.serializeArray();
    var obj = {};
    for(var i = 0, l = form_data.length; i < l; i++) {
        console.log(form_data[i].name);
        var obj2 = {
            value: '"' + form_data[i].value + '"',
            label: $("label[for='" + form_data[i].name + "']").html()
        };
        obj[form_data[i].name] = obj2;
    }
```

And the array is simply printed with print_r

[EDIT]
If you notice the first code block, this is the POST data from jQuery. It sends the objects fine with `form_data[cost[]]`.
But in the second code block, which is what PHP received, and immediately print_r()'ed, it loses a bracket resulting in `cost[`

Comment: Why do you think you need to do something special with the inputs that have brackets in their names?

Comment: show the actual code. json_encode()/json_decode() wouldn't mangle stuff like this unless the inputs were invalid to start with.

Comment: @MarcB — What does JSON have to do with the question? jQuery, by default, encodes an object to the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format (with PHP's square bracket extension).

Comment: @quentin: "Serializing as an array", which in jquery is invariably json.

Comment: @MarcB — No, as mentioned, jQuery will default to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: @Quentin So I basically wouldn't be able to have the brackets within the array of an object, is that what you're saying? Should I just have it as SerializeArray outputs it?

Comment: @ashin999 — serializeArray doesn't actually serialize the data. It puts form data in an array ready to be serialized. You don't actually serialize that data anywhere in the code you've provided, you just loop over it and populate an object with the data. It still isn't clear how that data gets to the PHP or why the square brackets are a problem for you.

Comment: ashin999 — I'm guessing you actually want something like `$ajax(url, { data: form.serialize() …` but it isn't clear.

Comment: So basically, the first code block is the POST data, and the second code block is what PHP results.

Comment: @ashin999 — and what is the problem with the PHP results?

Comment: Basically, I want to be able to save this form data so that it will be available to load back into the form at a later time using a $.each() and $('input[name="' + form_data.name + '"]')

Comment: Where you able to fix this? I'm having the exact same problem. If I check what console.log displays, it has all the information with the correct keys, that is, the closing square brackets are still displaying in the keys. If I check what a var_dump displays, it does NOT have the closing square brackets.

Comment: @AdrianCR I ultimately ended up not going this route. It proved to be clunky and didn't work the way I wanted. Instead, if I needed to output information, I used a template engine like Twig. Twig was able to parse the brackets properly